# How can I rip a CD to flac files in one step?

Tags: flac, wav, digital-audio

I'm using EAC to rip files to FLAC. Seems fine. But for a large amount of CDs (200 or so) the process is a little labor intensive. There's 4 or 5 clicks in there that seem extraneous -- EAC seems to want to rip the CD to a set of WAV files then (after all those files are ripped) I have to select "Process WAV files" (I'd get it exact, but EAC is occupied right now).

I'd like to send all of it to FLAC files in just a few steps: get cddb info, select art, rip.

Is there a way to do this with EAC that I'm missing? Haven't been able to find anything on the web that explains this.

Comment: Rather than rip to wave, just use the compress button and EAC will rip to wave and compress for you in one step. You could also try using the keyboard hotkeys to speed up the process.

Comment: @brian: that did it. Thanks. Can you make this an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than rip to wave, just use the compress button and EAC will rip to wave and compress for you in one step:

[image: Exact Audio Copy Rip and Compress]

You could also try using the keyboard hotkeys to speed up the process:

- <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd> for CD Information freedb lookup
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> for copy and compress selected tracks, which will copy all tracks if none are selected

Comment: I was assuming that Compress = MP3. Thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 0):

[CDeX](http://cdexos.sourceforge.net) will do this. Under Options -> Settings -> Encoding -> Encoders, select FLAC Encoder DLL, then rip CD to compressed audio file and they will be FLAC files. One button per CD once you have the right encoder selected.

You can also use it pull album/song title info to name all your tracks to a preset naming convention. Just make sure you have Autoconnect to remote freedb checked under Options -> Settings -> CD Database -> Remote freedb